# Buttons too sensitive in sliding fragments?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, slider, slide

does anyone have a suggested technique for using Buttons within fragments? I am currently using an onTouchListener. The issue is that when a user tries to slide the fragment.. its too easy to accidentally press the buttons. There are methods in the event class such as getDownTime() but this seems to retrieve the time from when the app was started. Any suggestions would be great! And onLongClickListener is too long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using an `OnClickListener` on the button, not an `OnTouchListener`.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help! this sorted my problem